# minimum of sum of two convex functions s.t. linear constraint

Tags: optimization

Suppose x is n-dimensional real, and f(x) and g(x) are real and convex R1.

I want to find x to minimize Q= f(x)+g(x) s.t. a’x=b, for a and b Nx1 real vector.
Lets call this solution X*
How is X* related to the two partial solutions X1 and X2 that optimize the following

X1 is the solution to Min Q1= f(x) s.t. a’x=b
X2 is the solution to Min Q2= g(x) s.t. a’x=b

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You're question does not seem to be related to programming at all, rather mathematics. It also looks like homework.

Comment: Not homework. A problem related to portfolio optimization in practice. Apologies if only programming questions. My first time, and maybe misplaced.  Sorry.

Comment: No worries, http://math.stackexchange.com/ might be the appropriate platform to ask. ;) But you should show some effort. What have you tried so far, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the direction.  I will take the question there and show what I have, but not sure about it.